# Core Data and Text format

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am making an app that has a text view in it. I have some simple formatting of this text (bold, italics, underline). But when I format the text it doesnt save the format. I was wondering if there was a way to save the text after I format it?

Not looking for you to write the code just wondering if it is possible and maybe if you are so kind as to point me in the right direction for some documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You try do something like this. stored UIFont Information to NSDictionary:

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0f];
NSDictionary *myFontInformation = 
                         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           myFont.name, "fontName",
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFont.pointSize], @"fontSize", nil];
```

And Save to CoreData.

If you retrieve you could the NSDictionary and re-create the UIFont.

CoreData Tutorial read a this article: [CoreData on iOS5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Appreciate it!